# Error in train from Caret

Tags: r, r-caret

I'm baffled.  I've used train before with no problem.  But now I'm repeatedly getting the "unused arguments" error.

```
#Generate random data
y <- rnorm(100, mean=.5)
x <- rnorm(100)
data <- cbind(x, y)
form <- y ~ x

fitControl <- trainControl(## 10-fold CV
                       method = "cv",
                       number = 8)

set.seed(825)
lmFit1 <- train(x, y, method = "lm", trControl = fitControl, na.action=na.omit)
lmFit1 <- train(form, data = data, method = "lm", trControl = fitControl, na.action=na.omit)
```

Since I am running a linear regression, I've specified this model both with x and y, and with form.  Both generate the same error.

```
Error in train(form, method = "lm", trControl = fitControl, na.action = na.omit) : unused arguments (method = "lm", trControl = fitControl, na.action = na.omit)
Error in train(x, y, method = "lm", trControl = fitControl, na.action = na.omit) : unused arguments (y, method = "lm", trControl = fitControl, na.action = na.omit)
```

In my actual data, I have many more predictors, and have played around with only including 1 or 2 predictors at a time, but all generate the same error.  Even the random data generates the error.

Any thoughts?  Help is much appreciated!  Thanks!

Comment: Is it possible you loaded another package that has a `train` function after you loaded `caret`, and that other `train` function is masking `caret`'s `train` function?

Comment: that was my first thought- but I've restarted R several times and only loaded zoo first.  zoo doesn't have a train function....

Answer (score 12):

I also had the same issue. It seems that there is another package loaded in your session that also has a function defined as `train`. 
Use `caret::train` instead of `train`

Answer (score 1):

you probably updated the caret package. If you look into the changelog from the package, you can see the following:

> **Changes in version 6.0-34**
>
> For the input data x to train, we now respect the class of the input
>   value to accommodate other data types (such as sparse matrices). There
>   are some complications though; for pre-processing we throw a warning
>   if the data are not simple matrices or data frames since there is some
>   infrastructure that does not exist for other classes( e.g.
>   complete.cases). We also throw a warning if returnData <- TRUE and it
>   cannot be converted to a data frame. This allows the use of sparse
>   matrices and text corpus to be used as inputs into that function.

Further in the help:

> x  an object where samples are in rows and features are in columns.
>   This could be a simple matrix, data frame or other type (e.g. sparse
>   matrix). See Details below.

And the details:

> The predictors in x can be most any object as long as the underlying
>   model fit function can deal with the object class. The function was
>   designed to work with simple matrices and data frame inputs, so some
>   functionality may not work (e.g. pre-processing). When using string
>   kernels, the vector of character strings should be converted to a
>   matrix with a single column.

I have no issue with the second train model, for the first model, just add data.frame(x) instead of x.

```
library(caret)

#Generate random data
y <- rnorm(100, mean=.5)
x <- rnorm(100)
data <- cbind(x, y)
form <- y ~ x    

fitControl <- trainControl(## 10-fold CV
          method = "cv",
          number = 8)

set.seed(825)
# changed x to data.frame(x)
lmFit1 <- train(data.frame(x), y, method = "lm", trControl = fitControl, na.action=na.omit)
set.seed(825)
lmFit2 <- train(form, data = data, method = "lm", trControl = fitControl, na.action=na.omit)
```

my sessionInfo()

```
R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Dutch_Netherlands.1252  LC_CTYPE=Dutch_Netherlands.1252    LC_MONETARY=Dutch_Netherlands.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                      
[5] LC_TIME=Dutch_Netherlands.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] caret_6.0-52    ggplot2_1.0.1   lattice_0.20-33

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.0         magrittr_1.5        splines_3.2.2       MASS_7.3-43         munsell_0.4.2       colorspace_1.2-6    foreach_1.4.2      
 [8] minqa_1.2.4         car_2.1-0           stringr_1.0.0       plyr_1.8.3          tools_3.2.2         parallel_3.2.2      pbkrtest_0.4-2     
[15] nnet_7.3-10         grid_3.2.2          gtable_0.1.2        nlme_3.1-121        mgcv_1.8-7          quantreg_5.19       MatrixModels_0.4-1 
[22] iterators_1.0.7     gtools_3.5.0        lme4_1.1-9          digest_0.6.8        Matrix_1.2-2        nloptr_1.0.4        reshape2_1.4.1     
[29] codetools_0.2-14    stringi_0.5-5       compiler_3.2.2      BradleyTerry2_1.0-6 scales_0.3.0        stats4_3.2.2        SparseM_1.7        
[36] brglm_0.5-9         proto_0.3-10
```